# Javascript - clicking back in the browser and saving previously manipulated html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

The website is a school, each school day has a set of 4 lessons with each lesson costing £7.50. When the user selects a day they go to a payment page where all 4 lessons are automatically selected as checkboxes, so the total cost is £30. The user can tick or untick each box to add or remove lessons which in turn changes the total amount on screen. The total amount is a html element with an id of #fullamount and a value of £30 :

```html
<h6>Total Cost : <div id="fullamount" name="fullamount">£30</div></h6>
```

The problem I am having is that if the user proceeds to the external payment page(after selecting all lessons they want) but then decides to click on the back button to return to the original page - the checkboxes remain as they were but the total(#fullamount) returns back to the original state of £30 so if they had only selected 2 checkboxes it should be £15 but it shows up as £30, then if the user checks the other 2 checkboxes the total becomes £45.

Here is the Javascript:

```js
$(".cell").on("click", "input:checkbox", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $total = $("#fullamount");
    var $target = $("label[for='" + $this.attr("id") + "']");
    
    var item_value = +($target.html().replace("£", "") || 0);
    var cur_total = +($total.html().replace("£", "") || 0);
    
    if ($this.prop("checked") === true) {
        cur_total += item_value;
    } else {
        cur_total -= item_value;
    }
    
    $total.html("£" + cur_total);
 $total.val(cur_total);
});
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 var $total = $("#fullamount");
  var amount = $('#amount');
  var thetotal = +($total.html().replace("£", "") || 0);
  amount.val(thetotal);

this.submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm finding it quite hard to explain but I hope I made some sort of sense. Looking for a solution and struggling with it a bit. Any kind of help or advice would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If it's an external page, and the back button is used, does the `onload` event fire again? You could recalculate in there. Otherwise, use localStorage for the amount?